# How can I generate a set of thumbnails of equal size without padding?

Tags: thumbnails, thumbnail-generator

I am looking for a thumbnail generator which will allow me to batch process hundreds of images and generate thumbnails of a specific size (200x150).  IrfranView kind of does this, but it will matte my thumbnails on a background color if they cannot resized to fit the destination size (if I maintain proportions, which I want to). What I want is to size my source large enough to the target size and then auto crop to fit the 200x150 size.

Is there a program that will do this, or is they some painless way I can go this in Irfran view?

Comment: For anyone reading this thread [Media Resizer](http://www.mediaresizer.com/) (a trailware app) is also worth checking out. Both ImageMagick and Infranview solutions referenced below also will work quite well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could still do this in a 2-step process in IrfanView.
First resize, setting the short side to 200 pixels (ensuring at least a 200x200 image). Then you run another batch on the result and crop to 200x150.

Comment: This is more or less exactly what I ended up doing.  I was surprised that the thumbnail support did not have a "smart crop" feature; you actually have to do this in the main application, and not in the 'Thumbnail' app, which is where I was looking for this functionality.

Comment: I had actually assumed the feature exists. Though when I tried to look up how to do it, I noticed it doesn't exist. Weird.

Answer (score 2):

[Imagemagick's](http://www.imagemagick.org/) `convert` utility will do what you want.

You need to specify the `-thumbnail 200x150^` option, where the `^` indicates to cut/crop.

You can find usage examples [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#cut).

Comment: I did not go with ImageMagick, however I never even thought of using it.  Thanks for reminding me about it!  It always seems to slip my mind.....